# re-write a string with text and numbers onto a newline and insert text

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, string

In Short, I want to split single line output string into multiple rows and label each raw with the hostname.

Hostname ProcessName CPUCore

output=$(ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking yes"  $ssh_host 'ps -eo comm,lastcpu | grep rrcp')

How to insert loop through a return out put that looks like.

```
rrcpd 17 rrcpd 0
```

and re-write as

```
Hostname1 rrcpd 17
Hostname1 rrcpd 0
```

Note

- The numbers can very from 0-32
- Hostname is a variable string $myhost
- The text does change, meaning it is not strictly rrcpd, it could be 
  e.g.

  rrcpd 17 rrcpd 0

  Cheese 3 cakes 8

  Cats 9  dogs  3

Command that run on each host

output=$(ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking yes"  $ssh_host 'ps -eo comm,lastcpu | grep rrcp')

The output can come back with 3-5 process when I remove the grep, hence I want to be able to split each output and add the hostname to the raw to label each output. I am checking what processes are running on each host.

rrcpd 0 rrcp_mon.sh 24

rrcpd 0

rrcpd 0

rrcpd 0 rrcpd 1

rrcpd 0 rrcpd 0 rrcp_mon 24 rrcp_mon 24

rrcpd 0

rrcpd 0

rrcpd 17 rrcpd 0

ard 9 ssh 32 httpd 21 bax 22

I have modified the provided below and managed to get it to work

```
#!/bin/bash
for remote in $(cat ssh_hosts2.txt)
do
    ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$remote" ps -eo comm,lastcpu |
    sed "s/^/$remote /"
done
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please add a proper example and result. For the given examples, the answer is valid. Please properly format you text so that we don't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: Why is the last line outputted if you grep for `rrcp`?

Answer (score 2):

please try this,

I have saved the given sample output in file /tmp/test.txt.

```
 xargs -n 2 | sed 's/^/Hostname1 /'
```

- `-n` means maximum arguments per line.

For example;

```
cat /tmp/test.txt  | xargs -n 2 | sed 's/^/Hostname1 /g' 
Hostname1 rrcpd 17
Hostname1 rrcpd 0
Hostname1 Cheese 3
Hostname1 cakes 8
Hostname1 Cats 9
Hostname1 dogs 3
```

Comment: There is only one match of `^` per line, so using `/g` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would see the type of data that you show (more than two fields per line in the output of the `ssh` command) is when you collect the output of your `ssh`+`ps` call into a variable and then output it without quoting it properly, as in `output=$(ssh ...)` followed by `echo $output` instead of `echo "$output"`.  Luckily, you don't need to collect the data in a variable at all.

```
while read remote; do
    ssh -n -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$remote" ps -eo comm,lastcpu |
    awk -v host="$remote" '/rrcp/ { print host, $1, $2 }'
done <hosts.txt
```

Here, `awk` is reading directly from the `ssh` command and also does the work originally done by `grep` in your code.  It assumes that it will get lines with two fields and will prefix each pair of fields with the given hostname (read from `hosts.txt`).

Alternatively,

```
while read remote; do
    ssh -n -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$remote" ps -eo comm,lastcpu |
    sed "s/^/$remote /"
done <hosts.txt
```

Here, we simply prefix each line with the hostname read from the text file.

Comment: I want to read the output in of a single line of string and numbers which is normally process name  followed by a number which is the core. Sometimes its a single text and number and sometimes it return 2, 3 or 4 processes with text followed by number. My aim is to get this command output  ps -eo comm,lastcpu and split each text number, text number ........ to multiple rows and label each row with a host name followed by text number.

Comment: @SaSa2929 Did you actually test the code I posted? The `ps` utility will only ever output two columns. The only reason you find yourself working with lines of more columns is that you `echo` an unquoted variable.

Comment: Thank you, it works, almost,  Tried it, it only reads the first host, how do I get it to loop to the next host?

Comment: @SaSa2929 Ah, I forgot, `ssh` would eat the data from the input file. Use `ssh -n`. I will update the answer...

Comment: I have modified it to use a for loop and it works now and returns all the processes, how is it possible to go one step further and provide a list of processes that I am interested in and ignore all others. I can defind the processes in an array of some sort, or include list, all others are exluded.


    #!/bin/bash
    for remote in $(cat ssh_hosts2.txt)
    do
        ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$remote" ps -eo comm,lastcpu |
        sed "s/^/$remote /"
    done